# How to change __builtins__ module variable?

Tags: python, python-exec

If you run this code:

```
src = "import os"
d = dict(__builtins__={})
exec src in d
```

Python says:

```
ImportError: __import__ not found
```

That's what I like to do, but when creating (or maybe loading) a new module:

```
import imp
mod = imp.new_module("foo")
src = "import os"
exec src in mod.__dict__
```

As you can see it runs, but I like it doesn't as in the above program. I like to disable all the built-in variables and functions. Is there any way to do this?

If you print `mod.__dict__`, you can see that it has `__builtins__` variable such as any Python module. I think I have to change its value to `{}`, but I don't know how.

Comment: So you want to *"disable all the built-in variables and functions"*, but not really *all* of them? What you're doing seems like a bit of a hack; what's led you to this need?

Comment: It sounds like you want to somehow run an arbitrary string in a "safe" environment. Given that you can do things like open files using the os module without having access to the open builtin you should be more clear on what you want.

Comment: I like to create a module with restricted __builtins__ global constants and functions (but just in this module), something like the first code (if you change src by "sum([2, 4])" it's an error too because python don't know how to execute this).

Comment: Yes, but **why**? If @CrazyCasta is right and you're trying to do sandboxing, see e.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/191623/110531

Comment: He seems to be trying to execute something in a restricted environment. Clearly the python-exec tag matches, and given that restrict doesn't have a description I don't really see the problem.

Comment: Yes @CrazyCasta, that's what I like to do, creating a "safe" environment

Comment: Obviously, if you don't have `__import__` in your module's `__builtins__` you can't use it to import anything. But more likely you want to put `os` object directly in yourself.

Comment: Yes @Padraic Cunningham, that's what I liked to do. It was very simple. I was trying to change all the __dict__ variable, but I can't because it contains private things. But when I do this, it works nice!! thanks.

Comment: @SebastianAlvarez, I added it as an answer when I read your question properly and saw I think *I have to change its value to {}, but I don't know how* ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I think I have to change its value to {}, but I don't know how.*

```
mod.__dict__["__builtins__"] = {}
```

Comment: If you use this and RestrictedPython, you can control  the most (I'm not sure if everything) of the insecure lines in your code.